# Linq2SQL, cast in mapping?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to linq and linq2SQL. I have done my homework, i.e. found many results and answers that target similar problems. Seemingly lacking deeper understanding of linq and linq2SQL I am at my wits end.

I have a web application with a simple html and js frontend. I exchange data with my aspx via ajax xmlhttprequests. All the data naturally comes in and is supposed to go out as strings.

What I am trying to do:

```
  private DateTime _date;

  [Column(Storage = "_date", Name = "date", DbType = "date", CanBeNull = false)]
  public string date 
    {
       get { return this._date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
       set { this._date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", null); }
    }
```

Instead of converting the string to a datetime in my aspx I would like to just pass on the strings and do the conversion at get and set. Running this code gives me an "invalid cast" error.

Am I trying to do something that is by desing simply not supposed to be done? Is my approach wrong? I don't expect someone else to write the code for me. I don't mind digging in the references, but I don't know where to start. So if someone where to point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for now:

```
[Column(Name = "date", DbType = "date", CanBeNull = false)]
public string date { get; set; }
```

Apperently linq or "whoever" is responsible can figure the casting out on it's own, if you let it. Right now that's good enough for me.

I have the feeling I will run into simliar casting problems later on and that different solutions may be required. If so I will update this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the cast problem is, it is not in the code you are showing.

Converting to and from a `DateTime` value in a getter/setter is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. The only thing that could happen in your scenario is that you get a `FormatException` "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." if the passed in value doesn't match a valid time string in your format - you currently do not handle this.

Comment: Thank you broken glass. I did have a problem with a value there. Above mentioned error is now gone. However I now receive   GenericArguments[2], 'System.DateTime', on 'System.Data.Linq.Mapping.PropertyAccessor+Accessor`3[T,V,V2]' violates the constraint of type 'V2'.